# Pass parent ID to new child list item in "inline edit" mode of ListViewWebPart

Tags: 2010, xslt-list-view-web-part

I'm trying to set up a 1:Many relationship between items in a parent list.
In the EditForm for the parent item, I've inserted a XsltListViewWebPart for the child list, and set up filtering on the parent ID.  This is working well so far, however my issue is with adding a new item to child list.  I would like the parent ID to be passed into it the new child item.

I've seen some guides on how to do this with using the query string when a new dialog/page is opened, but I would like to do "inline editing".  I'm assuming I can just write a javascript function to populate the column, but I'm not sure where I can hook it into.

I'm new to this, so I could be on the wrong track altogether too.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution? I having the same problem.

Comment: Nope.  I think I ended up customizing the new form heavily